# Attach an event handler to the immediate parent of all the span element with class refresh

Tags: jquery, html, css

I've come here again for a help and I'd appreciate suggestions.

I have a small project to work on. Well what I need is to use jQuery to find all the span elements with class refresh and attach a click handler to its immediate parent. I can use bind() of jQuery but as we know it does not work for elements which gets added in future. If I were in the old golden days I would have used live() but since it is deprecated I can not use this.

The other option I had was to use delegate function but with delegate function I'm not able to pass the selector parameter.

Here is my fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/ardeezstyle/hRhT7/2/

```
$('.refresh').parent().bind('click',function(){
             $(this).css({'position':'relative','background':'#fff'}).append('<span>').find('span:last').addClass('refreshing');

        _this=$(this);
    setTimeout(function(){
        _this.removeAttr('style').find('span.refreshing').remove();
    }, 1000);

});
```

I would appreciate any help.

Cheers!

Comment: You can pass a selector to `bind` or `on`. Problem is there's no selector for parents. Are you sure you can't give a class to these parents?

Comment: @Barmar Thanks for looking into my problem and trying to find a solution. Yes I'm sure I cannot give a class to the parent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since there's no selector for parents of a class, you have to delegate the handler to every element, and check at the time of the event whether it's a parent.

```
$(document).on('click', '*', function() {
    if ($(this).children('.refresh').length) {
       // do stuff
    }
});
```

Comment: This seems to be a good solution to me but will there not be lot of script running keeping the performance in mind since the page is really a huge one?

Comment: If all the elements you care about are children of something specific, you can replace `$(document)` with a narrower selector. Also, if the parents are all of the same type, you can replace `*` with an element type selector.

Answer (score 1):

use on delegated event

```
var parentID=$('.refresh').parent().attr('id'); // using id of parent.. you can get any attributes of parent here...if id is not present..
$(document).on('click','#'+parentID,function(){
   $(this).css({'position':'relative','background':'#fff'}).append('<span>').find('span:last').addClass('refreshing');

    _this=$(this);
   setTimeout(function(){
    _this.removeAttr('style').find('span.refreshing').remove();
   }, 1000);

});
```

it best to use the closest static parent container present in the document then the document itself for better pereformances.. [link](http://jq4you.blogspot.com/2013/02/jquery-direct-and-delegate-on-event.html) to read more about on event

Comment: Good practice is to attach the event to the closest parent that you know will never change. That way jQuery performs faster. Document seems so far away :P

Comment: @bipen I don't see this working. Can you please write a fiddle. I may be missing something. Cheers!

Comment: This won't work. The whole point of delegated bindings is to use a selector string as the second argument. If you call `jQuery()`, it returns the elements that match at the time you do the binding, and won't work with dynamically added elements.